# Speeding up a large process run over some data obtained from a database

Tags: python, mysql, django

So I am working in a project in which I have to read a large database (for me it is large) of 10 million records. I cannot really filter them, because I have to treat them all and individually. For each record I must apply a formula and then write this result into multiple files depending on certain conditions of the record.

I have implemented a few algorithms and finishing the whole processing takes around 2- 3 days. This is a problem because I am trying to optimise a process that already takes this time. 1 day is acceptable.

So far I have tried indexes on the database, threading(of the process upon the record and not I/O operations). I can not get a shorter time.

I am using django, and i fail to measure how much it really takes to really start treating the data due to its lazy behaviour. I would also like to know if i can start treating the data as soon as i receive it and not having to wait for all the data to be loaded unto memory before i can actually process it. It could also be my understanding of writing operations upon python. Lastly it could be that I need a better machine (I doubt it, I have 4 cores and 4GB RAM, it should be able to give better speeds)

Any ideas? I really appreciate the feedback. :)

Edit: Code

Explanation:

The records i talked about are ids of customers(passports), and the conditions are if there are agreements between the different terminals of the company(countries). The process is a hashing.

First strategy tries to treat the whole database... We have at the beginning some preparation for treating the condition part of the algorithm (agreements between countries). Then a large verification by belonging or not in a set.

Since i've been trying to improve it on my own, i tried to cut the problem in parts for the second strategy, treating the query by parts (obtaining the records that belong to a country and writing in the files of those that have an agreement with them)

The threaded strategy is not depicted for it was designed for a single country and i got awful results compared with no threaded. I honestly have the intuition it has to be a thing of memory and sql.

```
def create_all_files(strategy=0):
    if strategy == 0:
        set_countries_agreements = set()
        file_countries = open(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'list_countries'))
        set_countries_temp = set(line.strip() for line in file_countries)
        file_countries.close()
        set_countries = sorted_nicely(set_countries_temp)

        for each_country in set_countries:
            set_agreements = frozenset(get_agreements(each_country))
            set_countries_agreements.add(set_agreements)

        print("All agreements obtained")

        set_passports = Passport.objects.all()

        print("All passports obtained")


        for each_passport in set_passports:
            for each_agreement in set_countries_agreements:
                for each_country in each_agreement:
                    if each_passport.nationality == each_country:
                        with open(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'generated_indexes/%s' % iter(each_agreement).next()), "a") as f:
                            f.write(generate_hash(each_passport.nationality + "<" + each_passport.id_passport, each_country) + "\n")
                    print(".")
                print("_")
            print("-")
        print("~")

    if strategy == 1:

        file_countries = open(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'list_countries'))
        set_countries_temp = set(line.strip() for line in file_countries)
        file_countries.close()
        set_countries = sorted_nicely(set_countries_temp)

        while len(set_countries)!= 0:
            country = set_countries.pop()
            list_countries = get_agreements(country)
            list_passports = Passport.objects.filter(nationality=country)
            for each_passport in list_passports:
                for each_country in list_countries:
                    with open(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'generated_indexes/%s' % each_country), "a") as f:
                        f.write(generate_hash(each_passport.nationality + "<" + each_passport.id_passport, each_country) + "\n")
                        print("r")
                print("c")
            print("p")
        print("P")
```

Comment: Can you paste some code into your question? It is difficult to suggest optimizations without it. Your queries/main loop would be useful

Comment: Please do not use [Python] and things like this to "tag" your question, it does not help promote or highlight your question.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you are describing an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) process.  **I suggest you to use an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) tool**.

To mention some python ETL tool I can talk about [Pygrametl](http://www.pygrametl.org/), wrote by Christian Thomsen, in my opinion it runs nicely and its performance is impressive. Test it and comeback with results.

I can't post this answer without mention [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce). This programming model can catch with your requirements if you are planing to distribute task through nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, did not knew about his model.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a file for each country that you append hashes to, instead of opening and closing handles to these files 10 million+ times you should open each one once and close them all at the end.

```
countries = {}  # country -> file
with open(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'list_countries')) as country_file:
    for line in country_file:
        country = line.strip()
        countries[country] = open(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'generated_indexes/%s' % country), "a")

for country in countries:
    agreements = get_agreements(country)
    for postcode in Postcode.objects.filter(nationality=country):
        for agreement in agreements:
            countries[agreement].write(generate_hash(passport.nationality + "<" + passport.id_passport, country_agreement) + "\n")

for country, file in countries.items():
    file.close()
```

I don't how big a list of `Postcode` objects `Postcode.objects.filter(nationality=country)` will return, if it is massive and memory is an issue, you will have to start thinking about chunking/paginating the query using [limits](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

You are using sets for your list of countries and their agreements, if that is because your file containing the list of countries is not guaranteed to be unique, the dictionary solution may error when you attempt to open another handle to the same file. This can be avoided by added a simple check to see if the country is already a member of `countries`

Comment: That is a good idea, i actually can see there is an improvement in changing from appending to writing. 

Will modify my code with your answer and that from danihp to(hopefully) get improved times.

I was wondering, is it a way to calculate the optimum size of the page for the machine under which you are working on?

Comment: I can confirm that i did notice great improvement using this approach for writing. I am generating the files only modifyng that and according to my calculations i will be done by this afternoon. Which is good.

I Also used a raw SQL for getting the results. Only getting the data needed for the hashing improved the speed also.

Comment: You can use [sys.getsizeof](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof) to get the size of a single `Postcode` object to give you an indication of how many you can comfortably hold in memory. As with a lot of optimization, there is always a bit of trail and error